# Game crashes when calling collision in c++ UE4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I wrote a collision in c++, but it crashes as soon as it starts. Here is the code

.h

```
UCLASS()
class DIABLOCPP_API AHIT1 : public APawn
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    // Sets default values for this pawn's properties
    AHIT1();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Components")
        class USphereComponent* SphereComp;

    UFUNCTION()
        void OnActorOverlap(class UPrimitiveComponent* OverlappedComponent, AActor* OtherActor, class UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult& SweepResult);

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    // Called to bind functionality to input
    virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;


};
```

.cpp

```
// Sets default values
AHIT1::AHIT1()
{
    // Set this pawn to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    SphereComp = CreateDefaultSubobject<USphereComponent>("CollisionSphere"); 
    SphereComp->SetSphereRadius(100.0f);
    SphereComp->SetCollisionProfileName(TEXT("Projectile"));
    RootComponent = SphereComp;
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AHIT1::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay(); 

    SphereComp->OnComponentBeginOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &AHIT1::OnActorOverlap);
}

// Called every frame
void AHIT1::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime); 
}

// Called to bind functionality to input
void AHIT1::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);
}

void AHIT1::OnActorOverlap(UPrimitiveComponent* HitComp, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult& SweepResult)
{
    GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Yellow, TEXT("Some debug message!"));

}
```

Crashes when calling a line:
`SphereComp->OnComponentBeginOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &AHIT1::OnActorOverlap);`

I tried to bind a collision in the constructor, but even though there were no crashes, it did not work. I don't understand my mistake, in other more complex examples everything works.

Comment: It _might_ help if you posted the stack backtrace at the point of crashing, but that is not guaranteed

Comment: Sounds to me like something is invalid. Have you tried adding a breakpoint in BeginPlay right before the crash and check if anything is nullptr or invalid?

Comment: ShereComp nullptr, but why?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use `SetRootComponent()` method call instead of directly assigning the `RootComponent` variable. `SetRootComponent()` does some extra work behind the scenes for setting it up as the actual root component for the actor, as well assigning the `RootComponent` variable for you.

Now on another note, even with the above possible fix I mentioned, I have had these `nullptr` situations happen in rare circumstances, but on your clean pawn like this? this is just bizarre. It's usually some naming conflict with a component that somehow already exists on the actor.

In these cases, what I do is, rename the variable name, as well as the name string inside `CreateDefaultSubobject` to something else, like "Sphere Component" or call it "chocolate", or whatever really, just so it's different. Make sure you use the `TEXT()` macro too.

On top of that, just as a sanity check. I delete the `Binaries/`, `Intermediate/` and `Saved/` directories and the `.sln` file from the project. Then I right click on the `.uproject` file and `"Generate Visual studio project files"` and rebuild the entire game again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for giving an answer. When formatting small snippets of code such as function names and what not please enclose it in tildes ( ` ). It's common practice on the site and is much easier for people to discern code and improves readability. I've already submitted an edit to improve formatting, just for future reference. :)

Comment: @EdwardSeverinsen Thanks! That does look a lot more readable. I will remember this for future answers!

Comment: Alas, all the same. I switched my project to version 5, but the problem persisted. At the same time, everything works in an empty project.

Answer (score 0):

`CreateDefaultSubobject` with type cast shoud have `TEXT` type arg.

Change:

```
SphereComp = CreateDefaultSubobject<USphereComponent>("CollisionSphere");
```

To this:

```
SphereComp = CreateDefaultSubobject<USphereComponent>(TEXT("CollisionSphere"));
```

After it, your SphereComp will be created, and won't be nullptr (I hope so hehe)

Comment: did not help. ShereComp is nulltpr

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. Issue was solved when I added this the line in `BeginPlay`:

```
SphereComp->SetCollisionProfileName(TEXT("Projectile"));
```